# android How to enable or disable a dynamically created switch when data is entered into a edit text field

Tags: android, dynamic, switch-statement

I create a table with a switch and a edit text fields. What I want to happen is to set the switch to enable when I entry a certain text in the edit text field that is on the same tablerow So How to I set the switch in says row 8  to enable if I enter text in edit text row 8.

```
  for (int i = 0; i< dbarray_id.size(); i++ )
    {
        CODE IS HERE TO CREATE A TABLEROW

        //Now add a switch to the row
        Switch switch1 = new Switch(getActivity());
        switch1.setId(i);
        switch1.setTag(i);
        switch1.setSwitchMinWidth(50);
        switch1.setEnabled(false)

        //Add a edittext field to the row
        final EditText txtaccesscode = new EditText(getActivity());
        txtaccesscode.setId(i);
        txtaccesscode.setTag(i);
        txtaccesscode.setHint("CODE?");
        txtaccesscode.setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        txtaccesscode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(
            ....etc... for after change ...


        repeat for the number of rows in the database.
```

So when I enter text into any row the corresponding switch is enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate both EditText and Swith references in a class, then when textWatcher fires both references will be the expected.

```
public static class SwitchToggleListener {
    public SwitchToggleListener(final Switch switchView, final EditText editText) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {
                //Do nothing
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
                //Your own condition here
                switchView.setEnabled(s.toString().equals("ok"));
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your loop do this:

```
new SwitchToggleListener(switch1, editText1);
new SwitchToggleListener(switch2, editText2);
new SwitchToggleListener(switch3, editText3);
```

If you have too many rows maybe this is inneficient, there are other ways to do this, let me know if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The switch need to be final or a field.

```
final Switch switch = new Switch(getActivity());
```

Then you can access it on your beforeTextChanged listener, in there you change like always.

```
txtaccesscode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(){
            switch.setEnable(true);
        }
    }
);
```

After the loop reaching the end you can't access the variable anymore but it still exist. And on the next iteration of the loop the switch you create even having the same name is a different switch, because it's a new scope.

Comment: Don't see how that enable switch 8 if data is entered into textfield 8, or switch 9 if data is entered into textfield 9,,, the above doesn't pick the right one.

Comment: Because even if can't access the variable from the rest of the code because is another scope, you already define in listener that when the text in textField8 changes, the switch8 is gonna toggle, the variable still exists it's just accessible in that scope.

Comment: But how do you do set it to enable       switch(8).isEnabled

Comment: I add some information, i hope it helps you understand.